# Web-scraping a list of lawyers

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a program to get the names along with the titles of some practitioners out of a [webpage](https://www.otla.com/index.cfm?&m_firstname=a&seed=566485&fs_match=s&pg=publicdirectory&diraction=SearchResults&memPageNum=1). The content stored within disorganized HTML elements (at least it seemed to me) and as a result the output becomes messier. However, I've managed to get the output as it should be.

The way I've written the scraper serves its purpose just fine but the scraper itself looks ugly. Is there any way to make the scraper look good and still have it do the same job as it is doing currently?  For example, is there a way to eliminate the exception handlers?

This is how I've written it:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.otla.com/index.cfm?&m_firstname=a&seed=566485&fs_match=s&pg=publicdirectory&diraction=SearchResults&memPageNum=1"

def get_names(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    for content in soup.select(".row-fluid"):
        try:
            name = content.select_one(".span5 b").get_text(strip=True)
        except: continue  #let go of blank elements
        else: name

        try:
            title = content.select_one(".span5 b").next_sibling.next_sibling.strip()
        except: continue  #let go of blank elements
        else: title

        print(name,title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_names(url)
```

Comment: Can you define _"good look"_ a bit more precise please.

Comment: Without using `try:except:continue` block is what I meant by that. However, i didn't know that a working script can also get downvote here.

Comment: Is the intent of the scraper that you ONLY get this one page, or do you also want to get the lawyers on the pages afterwards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @scnerd already discussed avoiding the use of a bare `try/except` clause, I'll focus on removing it entirely.

After inspecting website source, you will notice that elements of class `row-fluid` are containers for each lawyer. In each of those elements, there is two `.span5 clearfix` elements, one containing lawyer's name and firm, other their specialization. Since you don't seem to be interested in the latter, we can skip that element entirely and move onto the next one.

```
for element in soup.select(".span5 b"):
    name = element.text.strip()
    if name.startswith('Area'):
        continue
    title = element.next_sibling.next_sibling.strip()
    print('{}: {}'.format(name, title))
```

You will notice I left out `row-fluid` container from the selector, as we are iterating only over the `span5` elements that are contained within them, however if you wanted to keep that it, you can chain the CSS selector as such: `soup.select(".row-fluid .span5 b")`. If there was any elements of the `span5` class outside of the `row-fluid` containers, it would be better to chain the CSS, making it more explicit.

`get_names` is a fairly ambiguous function name that also suggests it will return an iterable with names. What you are doing in this function is printing names of lawyers, together with the firm they're working for. I'd suggest renaming it to `print_lawyer_information`, or better yet `get_lawyer_information` and return a dictionary containing the `name` as key and `title` as value.

```
lawyer_information = {}
for element in soup.select(".span5 b"):
    name = element.text.strip()
    if name.startswith('Area'):
        continue
    title = element.next_sibling.next_sibling.strip()
    lawyer_information[name] = title
return lawyer_information
```

As you can see above, we're creating an empty dictionary and then, as we iterate over the elements, we append records to it. Once that is done, you just return the dictionary, which then you can print or do more things with. This can be done with a much neater dictionary comprehension.

```
return {row.text.strip(): row.next_sibling.next_sibling.strip()
        for row in soup.select('.span5 b')
        if not row.text.strip().startswith('Area')}
```

A couple other nitpicks would involve some [PEP-8 (Python Style Guide)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) violations, such as lack of 2 lines before function definition and multiple statements on one line. Run your code through something like http://pep8online.com and you'll get a better idea of how to make your code easier to read and follow. You'll thank yourself in a years time when you look at your code again.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_lawyer_information(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
    return {element.text.strip(): element.next_sibling.next_sibling.strip()
            for element in soup.select('.span5 b')
            if not element.text.strip().startswith('Area')}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.otla.com/index.cfm?&m_firstname=a&seed=566485&fs_match=s&pg=publicdirectory&diraction=SearchResults&memPageNum=1"
    lawyer_information = get_lawyer_information(url)
    for name, title in lawyer_information.items():
        print('{} | {}'.format(name, title))
```

Comment: This is undoubtedly the approach I wished to comply.

Comment: @Topto Do you intend to iterate over next pages of the directory? If so, look into creating a spider, with something like `scrapy`. Otherwise `requests.Session` is something worth looking into, for consequent requests to the same host.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use a bare `except` statement if it's not ***absolutely*** necessary. Catch the errors you anticipate and explicitly want to handle.

Also, there's no reason for the duplicated `try/except/else` statements, and no use, in this case, of the `else` statements at all. You can collapse everything into a single `try/except`, since you do the same thing regardless of which line throws the error.

You also have a little code duplication. Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY).

```
def get_names(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    for content in soup.select(".row-fluid"):
        try:
            element = content.select_one(".span5 b")
            name = element.get_text(strip=True)
            title = element.next_sibling.next_sibling.strip()
            print(name,title)
        except AttributeError:
            continue
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you put the entire body of the while loop inside the try block? And you can just leave off the `else` clause.

```
for content in soup.select(".row-fluid"):
    try:
        name = content.select_one(".span5 b").get_text(strip=True)
        title = content.select_one(".span5 b").next_sibling.next_sibling.strip()
        print(name,title)
    except: continue  #let go of blank elements
```

Comment: A slight little problem with this approach is that if in a container an address is none then the script will not print the name either. I meant, they both will get printed at the same time or they both will be overlooked if any item is none.

Comment: Yeah but that's the behavior of your original script also.

Comment: Right you are. I didn't know that. I just checked.

Comment: Maybe instead of `continue` you meant `pass`? That would allow the code to continue progressing through the loop body even if you can't find the value you're looking for. E.g., `try: x = ...; except AttributeError: x = default_value`

Comment: I tried that in the first place but it gives lots of blank lines between the results that is the reason I used `continue`.

Comment: Just add a condition that skips printing if they are both blank